# Iterated Law of Expectation in Linear Regression

Tags: probability, statistics, expectation, regression

Suppose $E(Y|X)$ exists. There exists a disturbance term $\epsilon$ such that $Y=E(Y|X)+\epsilon$ where $E(\epsilon|X)=0$.

I have trouble understanding the following simplifying process:

$E(Y-E(Y|X)|X)=E(Y|X)-E(E(Y|X)|X)$.

The second term on RHS simplifies to:

$E(Y|X)$.

Can someone explain this in detail? Thanks.

Comment: Do you know definition of conditional expectation?

Comment: @ZoranLoncarevic Clearly, not well enough. When you are conditioning Y on X, I understand we treat X as constant. But in the above expression, I don't understand how iterated process does any good because there is no X term in the "conditioning" part.

Comment: For a proper definition of conditional expectation, see, for example, [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_a_random_variable_2). With this definition in mind, answer to your question is simple: conditional expectation $E(Y|X)$ is $X$-measurable by definition, and $E(Z|X)=Z$ for every $X$-measurable random variable $Z$, again directly from definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $E[Y|X]$ is a shorthand for $E[Y|X=x]=g(x)$, so $E(E(Y|X)|X=x)=E(g(X)|X=x))=g(x)$.